# Import polygon shapefile with SPCC Sections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, import, united-states, land-survey, state-plane

I have a data set with records containing Township, Range and Section information but no X,Y coordinates.  I would like to bring in the data to ArcGIS with each section as a polygon or a x,y point in the center of each polygon.  Is this possible?

```
   #  name  date    time        T.N R.W S.E
    1 801   11/16/061100    A   64  9   33SE
    2 801   1/7/05  1122    A   63  9   7SW
    3 801   6/19/00 1352    A   63  8   34NW
    4 801   9/25/00 1455    A   63  8   26SW
```

What I am ultimately hoping to do is to make a polyline shapefile with the lines moving from one observation to the next but was thinking of starting with points and then working to lines.

Comment: This is the first time that SPCC sections have been mentioned on this site so to attract potential answerers I think you will need to provide more information (and preferably a picture) about what the numbers in your table represent.  I'm assuming that this is a US-centric term (which is not where I am from), and it sounds like it may be related to TRS and/or PLSS, so perhaps you can search here on those terms.